# move_upload_file() showing successful but file not being reflect in target folder

Tags: php, html, file

The code is showing the success message as the file have been uploaded but not being reflected in the destination directory. The destination directory has to write permission and in the root.

```
<?php
$currentDir = getcwd();
$uploadDirectory = "/tmp";

$errors = []; // Store all foreseen and unforseen errors here

$fileExtensions = ['csv']; // Get all the file extensions

$fileName = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['myfile']['size'];
$fileTmpName  = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
$fileType = $_FILES['myfile']['type'];
$fileExtension = strtolower(end(explode('.',$fileName)));

$uploadPath = $currentDir . $uploadDirectory . basename($fileName); 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if (! in_array($fileExtension,$fileExtensions))
    {
        $errors[] = "This file extension is not allowed. Please upload a .csv file";
    }

    if ($fileSize > 2000000) {
        $errors[] = "This file is more than 2MB. Sorry, it has to be less than or equal to 2MB";
    }

    if (empty($errors)) {
        $didUpload = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $uploadPath);

        if ($didUpload) {
            echo "The file " . basename($fileName) . " has been uploaded";
        } else {
            echo "An error occurred somewhere. Try again or contact the admin";
        }
    } else {
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            echo $error . "These are the errors" . "\n";
        }
    }
}


?>
```

```html
     <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           Upload a File:
           <input type="file" name="myfile" id="fileToUpload">
           <i
```

Comment: shouldnt it be $uploadPath = $currentDir . $uploadDirectory . '/'. basename($fileName); or change $uploadDirectory = "/tmp/";

Comment: @FatFreddy, as suggested will not work, check folder permission.

Comment: folder permissions are to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all is it Localhost or on an online server?
Second windows or Linux?
For now, check the php.ini for the Apache and search for:

```
file_uploads = On
```

It should be set to on. Also look for:

```
upload_max_filesize
post_max_size
```

Maybe you need to increase their values.

Comment: Localhost server.
file_uploads = on,
upload_max_size = 200M,
post_max_size = 200M

Comment: Ok check filesize limits this could be the issue

Answer (score 0):

check your `$uploadPath = $currentDir . $uploadDirectory . basename($fileName);`

e.g `var_dump($uploadPath); die();`

It might be that you have to put extra "/" in your Path instead of putting the strings together with "."